# Populating ComboBox

Tags: c#

My scenario is to populate combobox from the database, display customer name, and hold a value of the id using identity increment.

When this code is run, I receive an error `Procedure or function 'spSelectCustomerById' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied`.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
conn.Open();

//SelectCustomerById(int x);
comboBoxEx1.Items.Clear();

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("spSelectCustomerByID", conn);
//comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("cust_name", cust_name));
//comm.CommandText = "spSelectCustomerByID";
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("cust_id", SqlDbType.Int));
comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

SqlDataAdapter sdap = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
sdap.Fill(dset, "cust_registrations");

if (dset.Tables["cust_registrations"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    comboBoxEx1.Items.Add("cust_registrations").ToString();
}
comboBoxEx1.DataSource = dset;
comboBoxEx1.DisplayMember = "cust_name";
```

How can I populate a combobox from a database?

Comment: So What is your question??

Comment: Why are you doing `comm.ExecuteNonQuery();` and then filling the dataset using dataadapter, you don't need `comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: I think this code has some problems: aside from heavy SRP violation: you add a sql-parameter (cust_id) without setting the value; you add items and at the same time add a datasource/display member (you can use this - see Johnn Blades answer); You fill a complete dataset while you only need a table, ....

Comment: my question is actually how to populate the combobox from the database. it brings error which says Procedure or function 'spSelectCustomerById' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied. could somebody help me please

Answer (score 0):

For web combobox us `comboBoxEx1.DataValueField = "cust_id";`

for WPF you use `comboBoxEx1.SelectedValuePath = "cust_id";`

in win forms use `comboBox1.ValueMember = "cust_id";`

Comment: my question is actually how to populate the combobox from the database. it brings error which says Procedure or function 'spSelectCustomerById' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied. could somebody help me please.

Answer (score 0):

```
 conn.Open();

        //SelectCustomerById(int x);
        comboBoxEx1.Items.Clear();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("spSelectCustomerByID", conn);
        //comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("cust_name", cust_name));
        //comm.CommandText = "spSelectCustomerByID";
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int));
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataAdapter sdap = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        DataSet dset = new DataSet();
        sdap.Fill(dset, "cust_registrations");        
        comboBoxEx1.DataSource = dset;
        comboBoxEx1.DisplayMember = "cust_name";
```

// Add the following line
// You do not need to add items into the combobox.

```
        comboBoxEx1.ValueMember = "cust_id";
        comboBoxEx1.DataBind();
```

Comment: my question is actually how to populate the combobox from the database. it brings error which says Procedure or function 'spSelectCustomerById' expects parameter '@id', which was not supplied. could somebody help me please. i use this code for this but its not working..

Comment: if error is "@id", then why you passed the "@cust_id".
Try <Br />
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int));